# PHP Workflow Engine Framework

Tags: php, workflow

Is ezComponent Workflow still actively being developed?  I've downloaded their code and attempted to get everything working (using postgres db, php 5.4), but it continually fails with their sample code.  That being said, are there any mature PHP based Workflow Engine implementations out there that you can recommend?

Comment: The last update showing on the [ezComponent Workflow: ChangeLog](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/trunk/changelog_Workflow.html) is Monday 21 December 2009.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ezComponents are now known as Zeta Components.

See http://zetacomponents.org/ -- Quote: *Zeta Components originally were developed by eZ Systems under the name "eZ Components" and was generously sponsored to the Apache Software Foundation for further development. Since 07/2010 the components are known as "Zeta Components"*

This would explain why you're not seeing any updates to the main ezComponents site, because all new development work is being done under the Zeta Components project.